# SpTBX: show hint for X button of dockable panel

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

Using SpTBXLib. Dockable panels have X icon or right side of title. Is there a way to show custom hint (only simple string hint) when mouse is over this X icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `options` property to access individual items of a dockable panel.

```
SpTBXDockablePanel.Options.CloseButton.Hint := 'hint string';
```